# jQuery Only submit the form if at least one input field has value more then 0

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to Submit a form only when at least one of the field has value more than 0

All of the input field has same name and same class as it's a loop of the products. The default value of all the fields is 0 so the value of at least one of the input field should be more than 0.

Here is how my code looks like.

```js
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
  $('input.test').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 0) {
      return false;
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="test" name="price[]" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="test" name="price[]" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="test" name="price[]" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="test" name="price[]" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="submit"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I made you a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a reduce:

```js
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
  var sum = $('input.test').toArray().reduce(function(sum, element) {
    var num = isNaN(element.value)?0:+element.value; // find the number
    return sum + num;
  }, 0);
  console.log(sum);
  if (sum===0) e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="test" name="price[]" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="test" name="price[]" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="test" name="price[]" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="test" name="price[]" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="submit"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

If you do not want to run over all (i.e. leave as soon as something is filled in, you can use an each
That DOES allow submission of 1,a,c for example

```js
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
  var sum = 0;
  $('input.test').each(function() {
    sum += isNaN(this.value)?0:+this.value; // find the number
    return !sum; // leave the each when it is truthy
  });  
  console.log(sum);
  if (sum===0) e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="test" name="price[]" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="test" name="price[]" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="test" name="price[]" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="test" name="price[]" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="submit"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Genius :) Thanks a lot @mplungjan :) that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Store a Boolean value to track whether you should proceed with the submission and if you don't meet the condition, use the `preventDefault` to cancel the form submission:

```js
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
  let proceed = false;
  
  $('input.test').each(function() {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value > 0){
      proceed = true;
      return false;
    }
  });
  
  !proceed && e.preventDefault()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="test" name="price[]" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="test" name="price[]" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="test" name="price[]" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="test" name="price[]" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="submit"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks to @mplungjan for the comments that corrected the previous answer.  jQuery's each does allow for early termination so long as it returns `false` as the docs suggest (https://api.jquery.com/each/).  My apologies to anyone that was confused by this error as my use of jQuery has dramatically decreased since ES2015 + Babel/Webpack.